# angular extending a class to change the inputs

Tags: angular, inheritance

So I'm building an org chart, extending a third party lib:

https://github.com/dabeng/ng-orgchart

and I'm trying to change which things are displayed in the chart. Here's some sample data:

```
  datasource = {
    'id': '1',
    'name': 'Lao Lao',
    'title': 'general manager',
    'routing' : 'abc'
    'children': [
      { 'id': '2', 'name': 'Bo Miao', 'title': 'department manager', 'routing': 'abd' },
      { 'id': '3', 'name': 'Su Miao', 'title': 'department manager', 'routing': 'bcd'}
     ]
   }
```

I'm extending this class:

https://github.com/dabeng/ng-orgchart/blob/master/projects/ng-orgchart/src/lib/components/orgchart/chart-container/chart-container.component.ts

and trying to change one of the inputs like so:

```
export class OrgChartComponent extends OrgChartContainer {

  @Input() nodeContent = ['title', 'routing'];
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
Property 'nodeContent' in type 'OrgChartComponent' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'ChartContainerComponent'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

How can I make this so that I can put multiple things from the data into nodeContent? I don't just want the title, I want the routing number to show up in there too.

Answer (score 0):

The nodeContent property is string instead of Array of string in ChartContainerComponent (see [github link](https://github.com/dabeng/ng-orgchart/blob/master/projects/ng-orgchart/src/lib/components/orgchart/chart-container/chart-container.component.ts#L13) you posted). Assign single string value in OrgChartComponent

Comment: Yes, but I want to have both the 'title' and the 'routing' number in the nodeContent. How do  I do that? I've tried e.g.
`@Input() nodeContent = 'title, routing'` 
and that doesn't work either